# resuming an activity from a notification

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications

I have a notification in the status bar for my app:

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.parent, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.parent, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    ...

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;        
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

The problem with this is that when you press the home button from the app (pushing it to the background) then press on the notification in the list accessed from the status bar, it starts a fresh copy of the activity. All I want to do is resume the app (like when you longpress the home button and press on the app's icon). Is there a way of creating an Intent to do this?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent/39482464#39482464

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've solved this issue by changing the `launchMode` of my activity to `singleTask` in the androidManifest.xml file.

The default value for this property is `standard`, which allows any number of instances to run.

> "singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task. [...]
>
> The "singleTask" and "singleInstance" modes also differ from each other in only one respect: A "singleTask" activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily "standard" and "singleTop" activities) can be launched into that task. A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task — as if FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was in the intent.

you can find a detailed explanation in the [Android Developers' Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

I hope this helps

Comment: Also take a look at ```android:launchMode="singleTop"```, this may also fit  and is listed under "normal launches".

Comment: use any of (singleTask, singleTop, singleInstance), I found the activity task stack was broken, task stack cleared all the other activity

Comment: Using special launch modes "singleTask" and "singleInstance" should only be used in very rare cases, like when you are building a HOME-screen replacement. This solution is likely to cause more problems than it solves, unless your application is super-simple and contains only one `Activity`. The fact that this is the accepted answer and has 30 upvotes boggles the mind :-(

Comment: In my case the solucion was "singleInstance". Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't have any launchMode in the manifest, now it works as expected with it.   <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem and the proper way to handle this is to use the flags: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP like so

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

From the documentation this will:

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Answer (score 1):

I had inconsistent behaviour between devices with some intents loosing extras and the MainActivity´s *OnNewIntent* and *onCreate* methods both being called.

What did **not work**:

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Service:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("TEST", 1);
```

What **did work**:

Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Service:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent launchIntent = m.getLaunchIntentForPackage(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    launchIntent.putExtra("TEST", 2);
```

Comment: This one works properly up to Android 10 while classic `SINGLE_TOP | CLEAR_TOP` launches duplicate `Activity` right after calling `onNewIntent` for already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution this issue: I created *getPreviousIntent* method and gave it to PendingIntent that`s all:

```
private Intent getPreviousIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = am.getRecentTasks(1024,0);
    String myPkgNm = getPackageName();

    if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo;
        for (int i = 0; i < recentTaskInfos.size(); i++) {
            recentTaskInfo = recentTaskInfos.get(i);
            if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(myPkgNm)) {
                newIntent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        }
    }
    return newIntent;
}
```

Comment: how can we give it to pending intent? can you please share code

Comment: here ti is solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448840/android-how-to-open-last-activity-when-tapping-notification

Comment: This is a ton of fancy code to do a simple thing. You can just request a "launch Intent" for your application from `PackageManager` instead which gives you the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the corresponding activity in manifest file of your app.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

eg:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main_Activity"
    android:label="@string/title_main_activity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Comment: Using special launch modes "singleTask" and "singleInstance" should only be used in very rare cases, like when you are building a HOME-screen replacement. This solution is likely to cause more problems than it solves, unless your application is super-simple and contains only one Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can **simulate a launch intent** (as if the user clicked on your app icon to launch it):

```
val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)

val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, 0)
```

This way, you do **not** have to mark your app as "singleTask" or "singleInstance" in Manifest (which would create other issues). Thus this should be the proper solution.

**Note, however**, the above solution may not work directly for you, due to an alleged android bug. Discussions about the android bug and a workaround can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/1032613).

Answer (score -1):

I use:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

Not sure these are the values you need to set, but the answer is in those methods/flags.

Comment: I tried the above but it doesn't work, can you give a full notification example that works?

Comment: @EnesBattal sorry, I no longer have that code available (went a different way with my app.) The intent flags thing is one big mess. I don't think I ever really figured it out.