# Waze-like notification icon that returns to app

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity

I'm trying to add a notification icon to my application, that will function much like Waze's notification icon - when you open the status bar and tap on the "Return to MyApp" line, the application will move to foreground - with exactly the same activity stack state it had when it was moved to background.

I went over numerous SO questions, and found a lot of answers that are all very good if I know in advance which activity is going to be shown when the notification is tapped. I obviously don't know which activity it's going to be - it can be any of the app's activities.

I also tried sending a broadcast when the notification is tapped. I can the broadcast in my receiver alright, but from there I'm stuck with the exact same problem - I don't know which activity to launch - I can't find the last activity (I can only find the last task, but since my app has one task, it's no help).

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a pending intent.

Like this:

Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, Chat.class);

```
PendingIntent intent =
PendingIntent.getActivity(Chat.this, 0, notifyIntent, SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID);
notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

please see this link

[sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/20-Notifications/Patchy/)

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent)

Comment: This technique will show the 'Chat' activity - either a new one or an existing one. I want to show the last activity the user worked on (or is currently working on).