# Android Notification intent destroyes activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm trying to use notifications in my app, but I've got a problem using following code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("message");
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,StartActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(StartActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

When I return to homescreen and click the notification in the status bar StartActivity gets destroyed and created again. But, I just want the Activity to show again like clicking the launcher icon would do in this ,moment. How can I change that?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("message");
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,NotificationActivity.class);///!!!!
        resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

**NotificationActivity** is special class, which finishs immediately in onCreate() and brings the task of the app to foreground. Source: [Notification to restore a task rather than a specific activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Before you create the `PendingIntent`

Source:

[How to make notification intent resume rather than making a new intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent)

Comment: Calm yourself.

source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent