# android displaying multiple activity in saved state when notification click

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

I have a notification on my app. It works in foreground well. When i`m in a other activity and press home button after that i click notification. It opens given activity, but i need to display previous activity in a saved state.

```
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.service_state_0,
            getResources().getText(R.string.serviceStarted),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent i = new Intent(this, StartingActivity_.class);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this,
            getResources().getText(R.string.app_name), getServiceStateDescription(CustomService.this), pi);
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    startForeground(ContextConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID, note);
```

It always shows StartingActivity, the question is that how to call resuming activity when notification is clicked.  If the activity has not already been destroyed and i can just call that instance back(resume it) and therefore not needing to load it again and won't need to add another activity to my stack. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution like open recently activity in Notification:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.flag = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

Intent nIntent = new Intent();
nIntent = getPreviousIntent();

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getContext(), "some Title", "some text", pi);
nm.notify(0,notification);
```

---

```
private Intent getPreviousIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = am.getRecentTasks(1024,0);
    String myPkgNm = getPackageName();

    if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo;
        for (int i = 0; i < recentTaskInfos.size(); i++) {
            recentTaskInfo = recentTaskInfos.get(i);
            if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(myPkgNm)) {
                newIntent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        }
    }
    return newIntent;
}
```

you have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`