# android start activity without clear data

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I need to show previous activity when notification is clicked.It's working by using Recently Task way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904705/android-displaying-multiple-activity-in-saved-state-when-notification-click).I need to show previous activity without using GET_TASKS permissions. That`s why i store previous activity in a SharedPreference. The problem is that i need to show activity in a saved state. Maybe i need to add any flags. Please give me the best ideas.

```
if (!prefs.getLastActivty().get().isEmpty()) {
    try {
    activityClass = Class.forName(prefs.getLastActivty().get());
//                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    activityClass = StartingActivity_.class;
}
startActivity(new Intent(this, activityClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

}

Comment: use `savedInstanceState` check this developer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState)

Comment: I don't wanna start activity if shared has  previous activity. I just need to show previous activity like on Top i mean in a savedInstanseState.