# Get pending intent extra in activity with launcher flag

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

In my app I show notification in some cases and when user click on notification it navigate to app by this code:

```
Intent onNotificationClicked = new Intent(G.context, MainActivity.class);
onNotificationClicked.putExtra("DO", "clicked");
onNotificationClicked.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
onNotificationClicked.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent ponNotificationClicked = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 113, onNotificationClicked, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
this.contentIntent = ponNotificationClicked;
```

now in my MainActivity I want to get extras of this intent.but that is unavailable because this intent does not make a new activity and just bring the launched activity to front.so how can I handle this kind of intent in my app.

thank you

Comment: set the intent flag like below such that it will not create new activity intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: And you can use intent.putExtra and getExtra methods as it is...

Comment: where?should I use theme in oncreate or onrestart()??

Comment: You mean getExtraa() ?  then onResume()

Comment: yes where do I put getExtra();

Comment: I setFlags like you said but when I click on notification it recreate my activty.it not worked

Comment: onResume of MainActivity. Like String doString = getIntent().getStringExtra("DO")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98266/discussion-between-saleh-sereshki-and-shiva).

Comment: Please have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305088/how-to-make-notification-intent-resume-rather-than-making-a-new-intent

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

set in manifest in your activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and then for your pending intent you should to set like this:

```
Intent onNotificationClicked = new Intent(G.context, MainActivity.class);
onNotificationClicked.putExtra("DO", "clicked");
PendingIntent ponNotificationClicked = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 113, onNotificationClicked, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
this.contentIntent = ponNotificationClicked;
```

and now in your activity override onNewIntent and in it writ your function:

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getStringExtra("DO");

    if (action != null) {
        Log.d("this is creating", "shiva said right");
        mSlidingLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);

    }
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```