# Prevent notification PendingIntent starts Activity already started?

Tags: android

The service creates a persistent `Notification` and starts the main activity on click via `PendingIntent`. Here is the code.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewPagerActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(StreamingService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

However, if **the main activity is started** when I press notification, it will be started **again**, and again and...

In the end, I have the same activity pilled up, one on the top of another. I can see this by pressing the back button, which will kill the Main activity once and then get me back to the same activity until I close the last one.

How can I prevent this to happen? Can `PendingIntent` detect that aiming activity is running so it does not create the same activity again, but rather start the running one?

PS. I apologize if not being able to explain this well. If this is the case, let me know and I will rephrase the problem.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5631993/593709)

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with notifications; they are merely the mechanism for launching your activity but your problem would occur with any other mechanism. @etienne's answer contains what you need to fix it; another option is to use the android:launchMode attribute in your manifest to properly set your launch mode for this activity.

Comment: @mah you're right. I will fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the exact behaviour you want to implement, you could pass one of these flags as the last param of getActivity():

- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Comment: Thanks. Can you take a look at my solution? Anything you don't like there?

Answer (score 8):

I also found this solution. Add this attribute to `Manifest`

```
           <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"      // <-- THIS LINE
            >
```

for each `Activity` you need this feature. So far it work with no errors at all.

Which solution is better? Mine is easier, if nothing.

Comment: Sounds good, too. The previous solution (Intent flags) would be useful if you want to use different options for different cases; ie. depending on the user action, you may want to start the activity in a different way. It mainly depends on your application navigation schema, I guess.

Comment: +1 useful for me. To make this answer better check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html it's explain who it's work single top and catch this intent on the activity's method onNewIntent.

Answer (score 1):

Try using another value in REQUEST_CODE. **don't use default value 0** in REQUEST_CODE.

or your pendingIntent will restart your activity.

if you want to use normal activity cycle, input request value when creating PendingIntent.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, REQUEST_CODE,
        resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: "don't use default value 0 in REQUEST_CODE.or your pendingIntent will restart your activity." please share the source