# Activity restarts on notification click - android

Tags: java, android, android-notification-bar

I have an activity which plays music and shows notification

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final int mId = 1;
            mNotificationManager.notify(mId,mBuilder.build());
```

the problem is that as I go back from this activity lets say activity B, and I tap on the notification the activity restarts and now I have two streams of music playing, it seems as if the activity is duplicated

I had a look into the manifest to see if I can change something, and I added this line to my activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

this didn't help either, any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: what do you just want to click the notification and it goes away, thats it?

Comment: when I click on the notification I want the activity which threw the notification to open up where it left off, and not restart the whole mediaplayer and play the song again while one is already playing in the background

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in your pending intent i think, where you have flag_activity_new_task

Comment: use android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT cannot be resolved or is not a field :o?

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" still creates a new activity

Comment: it was just a guess from another post i seen i never tried it, it said PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT not just FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT StinePike is probably right

Comment: StinePike trick doesn't work, and pendingintent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT needs an assignment operator! what do I assign it to?

Comment: it should work just like this, is this how you have it   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

Comment: :( nope! doesn't work

Comment: check out the answer to this, this is probably what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934061/prevent-notification-pendingintent-starts-activity-already-started

Comment: Playing music wold be done by `MediaPlayer`, I think. So just stop the player on `onPause` or `onStop` of your activity.

Answer (score -3):

Please create global variable of `Activity` and check if it is not `null` then `variable.finish()` and launch the activity.

```
Activity globalVariable;
if(globalVariable!=null) {
    globalVariable.finish();
}
Intent in = new Intent(this,b.class);
startActivity(in);
```