# Resuming Activity from notification created by service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have an application which starts a service running on the background. This service periodically issues a constant notification. I would like to be able to press that notification and resume the last activity of the application.

I am creating my notifications as follows:

```
public static  void startNotification(Service service,  String message) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(service);
    if(prefs.getBoolean("pref_NotificationDisplayed", true)){
        // Creates an Ongoing Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service.getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Title").setContentText(message);

        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(service.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        toLaunch.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        toLaunch.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        PendingIntent intentBack = PendingIntent.getActivity(service.getApplicationContext(),   0,toLaunch, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(intentBack);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Send Notification
        Notification primaryNotification = mBuilder.build();
        primaryNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        mNotificationManager.notify(10001,primaryNotification);
    }

}
```

I have tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386542/resuming-an-activity-from-a-notification) with no luck.

Every time I press the notification a new activity is started up rather than resuming the old activity. Is this because I am issuing the activity from a service ? or am I making an obvious error above ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you try

```
toLaunch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```

inyour intent. check above flag i dont have tried...

Comment: Hi Jay. Yep tried it, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: in background activity open every time or it closed?

Comment: and one more thing have remove this toLaunch.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        toLaunch.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"); two line then above my code and try?

Comment: Hi Jay, removing the two lines with the addition of your code worked. Thanks for the help.