# Push notification click using TaskStackBuilder

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, taskstackbuilder

I'm setting an activity, Receiver, as the content intent for a notification.

```
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Inside Receiver Activity, I'm starting activities which are intended to be opened using TaskStackBuilder in the following way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(className));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addParentStack(Class.forName(className)).addNextIntent(intent).startActivities();
```

When the app is in the background and a notification click happens, it resumes the ParentActivity. Especially when device goes to idle and comes back. Any help? I'm cracking my head on this.

Answer (score 0):

For an **Android app**, you should also declare `android:launchMode` in your androidManifest.xml file.

As discussed in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode):

> An instruction on how the activity should be launched. There are four modes that work in conjunction with activity flags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_* constants) in `Intent` objects to determine what should happen when the activity is called upon to handle an intent.
>
> They are:
>
> - "standard"
> - "singleTop"
> - "singleTask"
> - "singleInstance"
>
> The default mode is "standard".

Solution given in this SO post - [resuming an activity from a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386542/resuming-an-activity-from-a-notification) might also help.